# In app email pop up not working for iOS 8 in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

The email popup is not working in iOS 8 (Xcode 6). This popup is working fine in iOS 7 (Xcode 5). This pop up never works on simulator and on the device sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Also I have seen the case that when i debug and execute each lines on debugging mode, it works but not so when I directly execute. Here's the code for `MFMailComposerViewController` inside the `emailButtonPressed()` method. Please suggest how can i solve this issue.

```
- (IBAction)emailButtonPressed:(id)sender {
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] == NO)
{
    //Mail not configured correctly
    CustomAlertView *alert = [[CustomAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Email", @"HDR") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Email is not Configured", @"INF") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", @"BTN") otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];
    return;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kShowBusyIndicatoryEventName object:self];
MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailPicker setSubject:@""];

// Set up recipients
NSString *emailBody = @" ";
NSString *fileName = @" ";
[mailPicker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
mailPicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.16 green:0.16 blue:0.16 alpha:1.0];

UIViewController *viewToCreate = [self.delegate viewControllerForPDF:self];

// set attachment file name and subject
if(viewToCreate)
{
    if([viewToCreate isKindOfClass:[PDFPlaceOrderFinalizeViewController class]])
    {
        PDFPlaceOrderFinalizeViewController *pdfViewController = (PDFPlaceOrderFinalizeViewController *)viewToCreate;
        if(pdfViewController.showPendingOrderView)
        {
            fileName = NSLocalizedString(@"Quote.pdf", "PDF");
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = NSLocalizedString(@"Order.pdf", "PDF");
        }
        [mailPicker setSubject:pdfViewController.emailSubject];

    }
    else if([viewToCreate isKindOfClass:[PDFOrderGuideViewController class]])
    {
        PDFOrderGuideViewController *pdfViewController = (PDFOrderGuideViewController *)viewToCreate;
        fileName = NSLocalizedString(@"OrderGuide.pdf", "PDF");
        [mailPicker setSubject:pdfViewController.emailSubject];
    }
    NSData *data= [self createPDFfromUIView:viewToCreate];
    [mailPicker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];
}

[self presentModalViewController:mailPicker animated:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kHideBusyIndicatoryEventName object:self];
[self.delegate dismissPopOver];
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". Error? Unexpected behavior (what specifically)?

Comment: FYI, Mail.app is not installed on simulator, that's why it never works in simulator.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen But the simulator generally has no issue showing an `MFMailComposeViewController`. The lack of Mail app is irrelevant.

Comment: @rmaddy The pop simply does not come. it's just backs off to the initial screen.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen the pop up was working for simulator in xcode 5 (ios 7) and also in xcode 4.6.3 (ios 6), so i think the question of  mail.app installation is irrelevant to the original question